# Integrated Windows Authentication for Multiple Domains

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, windows-server-2003

I have Asp.net website for domain A users with the Integrated Windows Authentication.

Now users from domain B need to access the website.

But Domain B users receive pop-up window to input the authenticated information when they access the website

My question is:

How to configure the IIS or Windows Server to allow Domain B users to access the website without the pop-up windows for authentication, just like the users from Domain A.

Comment: Are they in the same forest or have a trust between them?

Comment: Gary,thank you for your reply. Domain B users can open the website as long as they input the username and password of Domain A. I'm not sure whether they are in the same forest or have a trust. How can I know?

Comment: Gary, not if he's writing the code in C# or VB.NET. What code are you using to authenticate right now? Are you strictly relying on IIS to do the authentication?

Comment: To jcolebrand, yes, I set Integrated Windows Authentication in the IIS.

Comment: jcolebrand, my thoughts were this is a server configuration issue; I digress.

Comment: Somebody helps. It's quite urgent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Check that you have a trust configured

Verify this by trying to add domains users from domain B to the file system where your IIS site is located.

1. Verify that the correct user group from domain B has access to file system where your IIS site is located. ( if not using domain users from domain B ).
2. Verify that the user that is testing from domain B has the correct group memberships.

And if running Kerberos authentication.

Check on client where the user is if you have a kerberos ticket by using command 
    "klist tickets"