# Basic Authentication Versus Windows Authentication for an asp.net mvc intranet web application on IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have deployed an asp.net MVC web application under IIS 7.0. and as it is an intranet web application , I have disabled, form authentication, basic authentication and  anonymous access services from my web site inside IIS. While I only enabled windows authentication service. 
But currently users who are defined inside the same domain which contain the asp.net mvc web application can login to the application, while users who are defined under another trusted domain (inside AD on remote machine) are not able to access the application (they will get a prompted username and password from their web browser, but will fail to authenticate).
So my question is whether I can define which domain And/OR which AD the windows authentication service inside IIS server should use to authenticate the login users ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891156/integrated-windows-authentication-for-multiple-domains ?

Comment: but in my case both domains are trusted , and i can ping the AD from the machine where that aspnet mvc is deployed. so the link you provide is not valid in my case :(

Comment: Do you run a Kerberos auth like suggested ? (I don't know if this is relevant)

Comment: from where i can check this ?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/31850/how-do-you-find-out-if-active-directory-is-using-kerberos-or-ntlm ? (seems to be in the AD configuration)

Comment: ok i see, yes AD uses Kerberos, but if this do not work i can ask our system admins to chnage it. but from my side i need to know that is requirment from IIS + asp.net mvc code point of view .

Comment: And what the command "klist tickets" does on the client ?

Comment: it will show the current domain name (the domain where the asp.net mvc is deployed)and some info

Answer (score 1):

What about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx ?

Did you tried declaring the connectionStrings as specified to the different ADs ?

Comment: thanks. you mean to add a connection string inside my web.config file?if yes i tried doing so , but i need to pass a service account user name and password to connect to the AD . but not sure how i can define the username and password inside my connection string , can you help with this ?

Comment: @johnG Or maybe you do not need to define it, as the user will try to authenticate directly against the AD (from website offcourse) ?

Comment: i have a service account to connect to the AD . but do you mean that i do not need to include it in the connection string ?

Comment: Try without for now, and with a forced user if this not solve your issue, in order to locate the problem

Comment: now i define the following   <add name="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://v800011.ad-domain/CN=Users,DC=v800047,DC=ad-domain" /> . where v800011 is the AD server name, while ad-domain is the domain whihc I  need to force my windows authentication to use. so is my connection string syntax right ?

Comment: I say "try, and analyze the probable error" ? ;) (also follow the Step 3 of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx, which talk about membership providers.)

Comment: now i wrote this insde my web.config   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://v800047.ad-tdmgroup/CN=Users,DC=v800047,DC=ad-tdmgroup" /> . and i do not have <membership> inside my web.config ,not sure why maybe because i use windows authentication, and i do not have form authntication ? But still users can not login ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45387/discussion-between-cubitouch-and-john-g)